# How do I send message from ServiceBusQueueTrigger Azure function to Durable Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I'm new in Azure Function, I have Service Bus Queue Trigger Azure function which is pulling data from Service Bus Queue whenever message gets pushed in Queue, I want to send the message to Durable Function from Service Bus Queue Trigger Azure function and then implement the Fan-In/Out logic. I have no idea how to send the message from Service Bus Queue Trigger Azure function or Is there any other way to Send message from Service Bus Queue to Durable Function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is utilize the `DurableClient` binding on your Function that has the Service Bus trigger. Check out the documentation for Durable Client functions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-types-features-overview#client-functions). There are also various samples that use it. Most of them are HTTP triggered, but the same principle applies with Service Bus triggers.